# Event handler and action listener invocation cannot close

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, awt

I am having an issue closing an event handler and action listener in Java using AWT and Swing. I have tried to close off the invocation of the action listener but it keeps complaining about missing closers that no other part of the program flags as missing. I cannot tell what is missing exactly as this is the only error left in the program and it doesn't have any auto-solutions. I am using eclipse. The code that is flagging errors is as follows:

```
Submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String ACID = "";
        ACID = ATMID.getText();
        String ACPSS = "";
        ACPSS = ATMPSS.getText();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (AccountN[i].equals(ACID) && AccountP[i].equals(ACPSS)) {
                Submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        ATMSI.setVisible(false);
                        ATMM.setVisible(true);
                        ERR.setText("");
                        )
                    }
                else {
                    ERR.setText("Your ID or password don't match an existing one");
                    ACID = ATMID.getText();
                    ACPSS = ATMPSS.getText();
                };
            }
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance for any help as this is driving me nuts. If any more code or context is needed I will provide it but it don't know all of whats needed/didn't want to make this super long either.

Comment: *I cannot tell what is missing exactly* - so take out ALL the code from the ActionListner and recompile to get a clean compile. Then add a couple of lines of code and recompile. Repeat until you know exactly what you changed then you will be able to fix your problem. Don't try to write your entire program before doing a compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addActionListener` code is missing some `}` and a `;`

```
           if (AccountN[i].equals(ACID) && AccountP[i].equals(ACPSS)) {
                  Submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                          ...
                      } // End actionPerformed
                    } // End ActionListener
                  ); // End addActionListener
             }  // End If block
           else {
```

I have added comments to show exactly what each one is for

Comment: Ah i see that makes sense i just couldn't see it till now. thank you for the help